# How to protect all routes, except one?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm using Jared Hanson's *connect-ensure-login* approach, and the docs indicate that it integrates with passport by mounting the `authenticate()` middleware at the login route.

I'm wondering if this means that only that route is protected? Or all routes are?

Also, I currently have retry count/lockout logic in my app but this module seems rather simplistic in that it only redirects on failure.  Can it be made to use more complex logic?

Comment: would be better if you provide some codes, or links to the modules you've used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect the routes by yourself. Since the order in which routes are defined matters, you would do eg.

```
// Obviously cannot be protected
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.send(...);
});

// Authentication
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('strategy', {
  successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

// A random unprotected route
app.get('/unprotected', function(req, res) {});

// From now on all routes require authentication
app.all('/*', ensureLoggedIn('/login'));

// Root of domain for authenticated users only
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send(...);
});
```

The `connect-ensure-login` module just defines a simple middleware and you could easily define your own that would do just what you need. I believe many or maybe even most use even simpler middleware to detect authenticated users like this:

```
var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
};
```